# Load partial array using Import-Clixml

Tags: powershell

I did this:

```
gci -recurse | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort-Object Length | Export-Clixml s:\Files.xml
```

And it created a file ~3 GB in size.  Can I load elements in order instead of the whole set?
I wanted to be able to access the file size, complete path, and modification time and didn't really feel like making a csv file out of it (especially since I might want more info later)...

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
gci -recurse | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } |
 select length,fullname, lastwritetime | 
    Sort-Object Length | Export-Clixml s:\Files.xml
```